# Calling a component function from within a function in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that is laid out like this:

```
var Entry = React.createClass({
    // executes code on a button press.

    onButtonClick: function (event) {
       // (do stuff)
    },

    // generates the entry list with a button and some info.

    render: function() {
        var entryList= this.props.data.map(function(entry) {
            // (convert timestamp into relative time, add some tags etc)
            return (
                <p> entry.information </p>
                <a onClick={onButtonClick} className="btn right" id={entry.link}>
                    go
                </a>
            );
        });

        // returns the html of the component

        return (
            <div className="entryList">
                {entryList}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I would like to be able to run the function onButtonClick from within the entryList variable in the render function but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. When running it the console says onButtonClick is not defined.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: onButtonClick is not defined
```

How do I "escape" the function? I think that `this.props.data.map(function(items) {});` is what is complicating the issue because I can access it just fine from if I move the button like this

```
        // returns the html of the component

        return (
            <div className="entryList">
                <a onClick={this.onButtonClick} className="btn right">go</a>
                {entryList}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should set `this` for `.map` - `this.props.data.map(function(entry) {}, this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working the way you expect it to is because the context `this` changes inside of the anonymous function passed to `map`.  `map` takes an optional second parameter, which represents the value of `this` that the callback will use.  So simply adding `this` as a second argument to `map` will solve your problem.

```
var entryList = this.props.data.map(function(entry) {
    ...
}, this);
```

Developers who use ES2015 can also use an arrow function to automatically bind the correct context of `this`.

```
var entryList = this.props.data.map(entry => {
    ...
});
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

The context changes. So you can do this.

```
var Entry = React.createClass({
    // executes code on a button press.

    onButtonClick: function (event) {
       // (do stuff)
    },

    // generates the entry list with a button and some info.

    render: function() {
      var self = this;
        var entryList= this.props.data.map(function(entry) {
            // (convert timestamp into relative time, add some tags etc)
            return (
                <p> entry.information </p>
                <a onClick={self.onButtonClick} className="btn right" id={entry.link}>
                    go
                </a>
            );
        });

        // returns the html of the component

        return (
            <div className="entryList">
                {entryList}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

or simply

```
var Entry = React.createClass({
    // executes code on a button press.

    onButtonClick: function (event) {
       // (do stuff)
    },

    // generates the entry list with a button and some info.

    render: function() {
        var entryList= this.props.data.map(function(entry) {
            // (convert timestamp into relative time, add some tags etc)
            return (
                <p> entry.information </p>
                <a onClick={this.onButtonClick} className="btn right" id={entry.link}>
                    go
                </a>
            );
        },this);

        // returns the html of the component

        return (
            <div className="entryList">
                {entryList}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: it is not necessary store `this` to variable. You can set `this` for `.map` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map - just pass second argument!

Comment: thank. Yes that is another way. i am adding that in that answer.

Comment: Arrow functions are also another option.

Comment: @michael he is not using es6 in his code as we can see his source code.

Comment: @Michael Parker yes, however I don't see where author uses `ES2015`.

Comment: The OP may not use ES6, but developers who happen across this answer in the future might be.